# Moving/Updating JSON based markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

Below is the jquery code on my website. A ADS-B recviver is uploading live .JSON filed with lat/long info of planes. I have made them into markers but they will only update when I refresh the page. I have tried set interval and done lots of research but have not got very far. 
Any Ideas on what I can do? Maybe I have not put the Set Interval in the right place.

```
function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.363, 175.044),
zoom: 5,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);



$.getJSON('https://crossorigin.me/http://radar1.ddns.net:3080/data/aircraft.json', function(data){
             $.each( data.aircraft, function(i, value) {


            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon, value.flight, value.altitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            icon: 'airplane.jpg',
            map: map,
            title: "Callsign   Altitude  "+value.flight+value.altitude

            });

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.008625, 174.785047),
icon: 'airport.png',
map: map,
});        



        });
});


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Kieran try the below code it refreshes the map after every 20 seconds.!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timerID = null;
var map;
var timerRunning = false;
var delay = 20000; // refresh every 20 seconds
var zoomToExtents = 0;
var openedInfoWindow = null;
// Initialize Timer
function initializeTimer() {

    initialize();
    StopTheClock();
    StartTheTimer();
}
function StopTheClock() {
    if (timerRunning)
        clearTimeout(timerID)
    timerRunning = false;
}
function StartTracking() {
    StartTheTimer();
}
function StartTheTimer() {
   // alert('hi');
    readData();
    timerRunning = true;
    timerID = self.setTimeout("StartTracking()", delay)
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeTimer);
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.363, 175.044),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
    function readData() {

        $.getJSON('https://crossorigin.me/http://radar1.ddns.net:3080/data/aircraft.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data.aircraft, function (i, value) {


                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon, value.flight, value.altitude);
                var Latlngs = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.008625, 174.785047);
                map.setCenter(Latlngs);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    icon: 'airplane.jpg',
                    map: map,
                    title: "Callsign   Altitude  " + value.flight + value.altitude

                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.008625, 174.785047),
                    icon: 'airplane.jpg',
                    map: map,
                });



            });
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hi Mohan, Thanks it works! Just a slight issue, the old positions are still showing any way to remove this and just show a line behind of ifs history please? or just one icon.